# How to cast context_info return value to xml

Tags: sql-server, varbinary, context-info

How can I do cast/convert `context_info` return value data to `XML`?

The first query works fine and query2 does not work

```
-- Query 1
DECLARE @xml XML = '<row User="system" Log="1" Culture="1"/>'
DECLARE @varB VARBINARY(128);

SET @varB = CAST(@xml AS VARBINARY(128)) 

SELECT @xml, CAST(@varB AS XML)

-- Query 2
DECLARE @xml XML = '<row User="system" Log="1" Culture="1"/>'
DECLARE @varB VARBINARY(128);

SET @varB = CAST(@xml AS VARBINARY(128)) 

SET CONTEXT_INFO  @varB

SELECT @xml, CAST(@varB AS XML), CONTEXT_INFO(), CAST(CONTEXT_INFO() AS XML)
```

Error:

> XML parsing: line 1, character 41, illegal xml character

Comment: `CONTEXT_INFO` is `binary(128)` rather than `varbinary(128)`. The parsing error is due to the trailing binary zeros being evaluated. What SQL Server version are you using?

Comment: sql server 2016   . solution؟

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`CONTEXT_INFO` is fixed-length `binary(128)` rather than `varbinary(128)`. The parsing error is due to the trailing binary zeros being evaluated.

Instead of `CONTEXT_INFO`, consider using [`SESSION_CONTEXT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/session-context-transact-sql) (available in SQL Server 2016 onwards). `SESSION_CONTEXT` allows one to store one or more key/value pairs with a `sysname` key type (`nvarchar(128)`) and a value of type `sql_variant` with [`sp_set_session_context`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-set-session-context-transact-sql). The value can be retrieved with the `SESSION_CONTEXT` function.

So if your underlying objective is to store and retrieve the User, Log, and Culture values, you could create `SESSION_CONTEXT` entries for the 3 values instead of `XML`:

```
EXEC sp_set_session_context @key= N'User', @value= 'system';
EXEC sp_set_session_context @key= N'Log', @value= 1;
EXEC sp_set_session_context @key= N'Culture', @value= 1;
SELECT SESSION_CONTEXT(N'User'), SESSION_CONTEXT(N'Log'), SESSION_CONTEXT(N'Culture');
```

You could alternatively use XML similarly to your original attempt but, since `XML` is not a permitted `sql_variant` type, you'll need to add the `XML` value as varchar/nvarchar and `CAST` to `XML`:

```
DECLARE @xml XML = '<row User="system" Log="1" Culture="1"/>';
DECLARE @xmlVarchar varchar(8000) = CAST(@xml AS varchar(8000));
EXEC sp_set_session_context @key= N'xml', @value= @xmlVarchar;
SELECT CAST(CAST(SESSION_CONTEXT(N'xml') AS varchar(8000)) AS xml);
```